# JavaScript $.post() not working with Laravel 5.4

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, routes, httprequest

I am trying to use JavaScript $.post() function in my Laravel project but it does not work.

Following is my JavaScript function

```
<script>

    function edit_city(id){
    //window.location.href = "editcity/"+id;
    var url= '{{url("editcity")}}' + ' /' +id;

    $.post(url, function(page_response)
    {
        alert(page_response);
    });
    }
    </script>
```

This is my route:

```
Route::post('editcity/{city_id}', function () {
    return "view";
});
```

The page does not give any response. It does not show any error as well. I tired the following JavaScript and it worked fine.

```
<script>

    function edit_city(id){
    window.location.href = "editcity/"+id;
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two reasons why this won't work. First is that you have a space in `' /'` which makes the route invalid. Remove the space and change it to `'/'`. Secondly this is a post request and you need a csrf token, without which you'd get a csrf mismatch error.

```
<script>
    function edit_city(id) {
        var url = '{{url("editcity")}}' + '/' +id;

        $.post(url, {_token: '{{ csrf_token() }}'}, function(page_response) {
            alert(page_response);
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works. but now instead of alert, I want to do something like this: $(".modal-body").html(page_response); It works with alert but does not work this .html(page_response).

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `$.post()` shorthand you are using is [incorrect](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/). Are you able to get the full `$.ajax()` method to work? Something like:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  success: function(page_response){ alert(page_response); }
});
```